# Flex - How To Modify The Verticle Gap In A Repeater

Tags: apache-flex, repeater

I Have a VBox, and set the verticleGap = 0. Inside the VBox I have a Repeater. When I run the App, the items listed from the Repeater have a large gap between each line. Is there a way to set the verticleGap on the Repeater, or reduce that space?

Thanks

Comment: It would help if you posted some code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things: First, the property is misspelled, it should be "verticalGap" for your VBox.  Second, if your repeated components are all the same height, you could set an explicit height for your Repeater component, such as height="22".  Hope that helps.

Comment: Sorry about the typo. So the height set on the Repeater, isn't the height of the entire area. Duh! Makes sense. I do have a height set on the Repeater. Let me adjust it. Thanks

Comment: Also, if this answer was helpful for you, feel free to upvote it. ;)